# systemd-analyze blame output

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd

I think I have a problem.

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
30.308s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
28.819s plymouth-quit-wait.service
28.588s dev-sdb2.device
23.005s snapd.service
20.796s dev-loop23.device
20.628s dev-loop19.device
20.078s dev-loop17.device
19.816s dev-loop22.device
19.795s dev-loop20.device
19.782s dev-loop21.device
19.058s dev-loop18.device
17.972s dev-loop24.device
17.389s dev-loop14.device
17.363s dev-loop11.device
17.072s dev-loop15.device
16.805s dev-loop9.device
16.491s dev-loop10.device
16.181s dev-loop13.device
```

That is just the beginning. Those lines appear 7 times. I don't know, but I think that means they are running 7 times. I have a long boot time.

Am I right? What is going on and how do I fix it?

I am thinking about reinstalling Ubuntu.

I also ran `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
graphical.target @1min 28.186s
└─multi-user.target @1min 28.186s
  └─windscribe-cli.service @1min 22.483s +5.702s
    └─network-online.target @1min 22.479s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @52.170s +30.308s
        └─NetworkManager.service @41.210s +10.957s
          └─dbus.service @40.343s
            └─basic.target @40.335s
              └─sockets.target @40.334s
                └─snapd.socket @40.285s +49ms
                  └─sysinit.target @40.284s
                    └─apparmor.service @33.773s +6.510s
                      └─local-fs.target @33.768s
                        └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 27.283s
                          └─swap.target @33.530s
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-56d0f859\x2ddbe4\x2d42d9\x2db3
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-56d0f859\x2ddbe4\x2d42d9\x2d
lines 1-20/20 (END)
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Also show us `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. There are many possible causes for slow boot. Snaps are only one ingredient in a rich stew.

Comment: Ok I ran systemd-analyze critical-chain

Comment: I don't know enough, but most slow boots would only have a few of your times.  Think it would be good to edit your question with your computer specs and also how much space is used on your drive/s and if they are HD +speed or SSD.

Comment: Critical chain: You are spending 11 seconds initializing the interfaces and starting network connections, another 30 seconds simply waiting for the network to become available, and yet another 5 seconds connecting to your VPN (Windscribe). Looks like over 50% of your boot time is ordinary networking (not snaps).

Answer (score 0):

*dev-loop*.device* lines show the loading apps installed by Snap, [discussed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/a364ii/proscons_of_snap_vs_apt/) and if those apps are uninstalled, then you don't wait for them to load.

Apps installed Old School with [apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html) don't consume as much time or memory.

Snaps are not necessarily eeevil; [developers like them](https://www.fosslinux.com/10380/what-are-snaps-and-how-to-install-it-on-various-linux-distributions.htm).

Comment: But why is it happening over and over. Once is enough. Are you saying everything can be installed with apt?

Comment: "But why is it happening over and over. Once is enough. " Don't know.   "Are you saying everything can be installed with apt?" This early in the game, don't believe there are any Snap-only packages. Maybe years from now Snap will take over, but since Snap is being pushed by Canonical, if a dev wants to write for other distros, they will likely still package for apt.